# comment line is not being escape if it is in same line code from my input.txt file with python

Tags: python, file

I have lines containing comments marked by `//` in my `input.txt` file:

**Input File**

```
something
something // something something
// something something
something
```

Here line 3 is being skipped, but line 2 is not.

**My Code**

```
for line in (l for l in open('input.txt', mode='r') if not l.lstrip().startswith('//')):
    f_write.write(line)
```

The same code rewritten as a reusable function:

```
def skip_comments(file):
    for line in file:
        if not line.lstrip().startswith('//'):
            yield line

f = open('input.txt')
for line in skip_comments(f):
    f_write.write(line)
```

Both snippets produce the same result. I've tried many times to open with different mode and string but without `lstrip`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Does line 2 `startswith` a double slash in your opinion?

Comment: `startswith` will only check start not in middle.

Comment: Oh Yes. Thanks skaul05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should write your code like this:

```
def skip_comments(file):
for line in file:
    if not line.lstrip().startswith('//'):
        line = line.split("//")
        yield line[0]
```

**update**

if you want to check more complex comment i suggest the code below:

```
def skip_comments(file):
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('//'):
        continue
    elif line.find("/*")>=0:
        startIndex = line.find("/*")
        endIndex = line.find("*/")
        line = line[:startIndex] + line[endIndex + len("*/"):]
        yield line
    else
        line = line.split("//")[0]
        yield line
```

and you can put middle part in while like this so it removes all the comments in line:

```
def skip_comments(file):
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('//'):
        continue
    elif line.find("/*")>=0:
        while(line.find("/*")>=0):
            startIndex = line.find("/*")
            endIndex = line.find("*/")
            line = line[:startIndex] + line[endIndex + len("*/"):]
        yield line
    else
        line = line.split("//")[0]
        yield line
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Abbas Dehghan

Comment: Hello Abbas Dehghan, if i wanna check more condition suppose comment line start with /* and end it by */ we know it already. So in this case i can't more check within one line with in your 3 number line here if not line.lstrip().startswith('//'): if i use here 'or' or 'and' such like as if not line.lstrip().startswith('//') or line.lstrip().startswith('/*') and line.lstrip().endswith('*/'): and same rule i've flowed under code but working only first condition here. Have i used to another condition for this?

Comment: Mainly i wanted to know that both comment line  // and /* */ contains in my code. So in this case i can't use here within one condition. Individually it's working fine.

Comment: Oh yes just mind  i've used there elif for checking and it's fine but my output file is being noisy a little.

Comment: Thanks. Your first update code works simply for one line and in the case of middle in comment your second update code may be has some lack when using loop. When that is getting new line for example /*something newline something*/ and this time your loop is being infinity and that's why computer is hanging.

Answer (score 2):

[`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) checks exactly what its name implies: whether a string starts with the requested prefix it not. No amount of stripping leading whitespace with [`lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) is going to magically expose comments starting in the middle of a line.

A better option would be [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), which returns the index of the comment on the line.

```
def skip_comments(file):
    for line in file:
        index = line.find('//')
        if index >= 0:
            yield line[:index]
        else:
            yield line
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mad Physicist

Comment: Yes i've done it according to my question. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Sorry i forgot it. Now it's okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if `//` is in your line and just keep the text that appears before `//`

```
for line in (l.split('//')[0].strip() for l in open('input.txt', mode='r') if l.split('//')[0].strip()):
        f_write.write(line)
```